# Capture high resolution still image from USB camera in OS x

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, image-capture

I need to capture still image from USB camera. The camera supports different high resolution for still image capture.

Currently I am using AVCapture and AVCaptureStillImageOutput but it is not able to capture image from device in stillImage mode.

There is API available in AVFoundation 'highResolutionStillImageDimensions' but it is only for iOS.

Is there any way to do this in OS X using objective c ?